# How to overlay a finger drawing canvas on an image in Android?

Tags: android, trace, paint

I am developing an Android application that is designed to teach children how to write letters of my native language (Telugu) by overlaying a finger drawable canvas on top of an image of the letter. Currently, I have adapted the Android gesture overlay to serve that purpose. How can I overlay an actual fully functional canvas that is transparent on which one can finger trace the letter underneath? I am looking to implement a canvas like the one in the APIDemos ([TouchPaint](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html)). I am trying to achieve something like [this](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aimkara.HindiLessons1Lite). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a custom view which can detect touch gestures. You can follow the same tutorial as the touch paint in api demos, it should serve your need.

Regarding being a transparent over lay, you can use framelayout as top level parent layout and make sure that your custom view is on top of the imageview (considering that your letter will be an image view)

hope this helps

Comment: Madhusudhan, thank you for your quick answer. I do believe I have tried this (overlaying the TouchPaint on top of my ImageView) before, but it did not work. I unfortunately can not remember what went wrong. Could you provide some code to build on? Thank you again.